# Transform hierarchy to sequence of route fragments

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Suppose I got a deeply nested structure, such as a hierarchy of departments or sections,

```
export interface ISection {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    sections: ISection[];
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to transform this into an URL such as

```
http://my.domain.org/section/23/56/101
```

(#101 is a subsection of #56, which is a subsection of #23), so that Angular's router could translate this into an array, for example. Naive approach:

```
{ path: section/:[ids]',  component: SectionComponent }
```

> error_handler.js:55 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'section'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'section'

The way the Angular (2) router works though, you have to have a fixed number of IDs, so while

```
{ path: 'section/:id1/:id2/:id3',  component: SectionComponent }
```

might work alright for the above example

```
http://my.domain.org/section/23/56/101/43
```

will not. I would imagine that

```
http://my.domain.org/section/23/56
```

is still going to work, but `id3` would be undefined.

Can this be done in some way? I'm on v4.0.0-beta.4.

Comment: What is `section/:[ids]'` supposed to do? The would create a route with a parameter named `[ids]`.

Comment: You could use  a child route to the `section` route with path `**` (match anything) and then do the parsing of the remaining route yourself in a guard applied to the `**` route.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that is why I called it a naive approach, it pseudo-code, so to speak. If I were to implement this feature, that is how I might do it.

Comment: Now there's an idea - thanks Günter, I'll give it a shot!